# Django's REST framwork Quickstart Error

Tags: python, django

I followed all the steps from the tutorial [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/). But when I try to run the server I get the following error  further down. Since I am new to django i am unsure where  to start to debug.

The full console output can be found [Here](https://pastebin.com/tFzcUqm3)

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f4e9dc9c7d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/djangoApi/tutorial/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
 .....
ValueError: Empty module name
```

My database settings in `settings.py` is

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
} 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'None',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doc` says `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` and `PAGE_SIZE` are `None` by default. So you don't have to specify that unless you want. Just remove the `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` from the `REST_FRAMEWORK` and all good to go.

Comment: Wow that was very nice. Even though the tutorial wants to enable pagination

Comment: Yeah noted that. They said like to turn on pagination but forgot to include in settings.